# Star Wars 30-stud long grey triangle ship identification

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Tried searching it through Google but it didn’t come up with a result. Please help me identifying this one.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the [MIDI-SCALE IMPERIAL STAR DESTROYER™ - 8099](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=91475#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)